# Unable to login to my server using ssh

Tags: debian, ssh, login, authentication, key-authentication

Yesterday I was migrating to my new server, needed to use rsync, I created a RSA key, so that rsync could connect, I saw an error that says `add to trusted key in location x` I didn't have that location on my new server, so basically when I do `mv rsakey /location.x` The directory didn't exist.

I tried regenerating the key. but that didn't help, now I'm unable to login to ssh nor to filezilla `scp protocol` it says

`Error: Network error: Software caused connection abort. Error: Could not connect to server`

I'm almost certain that the error is caused by RSA key. How can I fix it? By the way I have [Ispcp](http://isp-control.net/) installed, so I might be able to fix it from there.

**Note:** I have generated RSA keys on the old and the new server, I can login to the old but not the new one.

**EDIT**

using terminator on ubuntu 12.04:

```
$ ssh root@server_ip
Connection closed by server_ip
```

**EDIT 2**

after doing `mv ~/.ssh ssh_backup` i tried to connect and it says `Read from socket failed: Connection reset by peer` i retried and it gave me the `connection closed` error shown above

**EDIT 3**

the output of `ssh -vv root@server_ip`

```
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to my_ip_address [my_ip_address] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/me/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-6+squeeze3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection closed by my_ip_address
```

**@mattdm** I named the location `x` because i forgot what it was, you know that error where it basically says: please move rsa key to trusted sources location, or something like that. maybe it was `/.ssh`

Comment: Can you be more specific about "location.x"? Was this in `/etc` or in root's home directory?

Comment: Note that a key error will generally give you permission denied from ssh, not the connection errors you are seeing. Can you run (from your ubuntu client) `ssh -vv  root@server_ip`? The -vv will add debugging output.

Comment: `needed to use rsync, I created a RSA key`. Are we talking about a host key or a user key? And on which server did you put it? Which server gave you that "add to trusted key" error. Then as mattdm asked, what is "location.x" (again, which server). Be explicit.

Comment: @Patrick please read my edit sir, and my new debian server gave me the error, i was using rsync on the old one, trying to connect to the new one... we are talking about host key

Comment: Okay, now it's time to look in your server logs. The connection-closed after `SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT` is _very early in the process. Something is almost certainly messed up in `/etc`.

Comment: @mattdm any suggestions to fix it?

Comment: It depends what's wrong. Your server logs will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

One, rather drastic, way of fixing this would be to delete your ssh credentials. On your local machine:

```
mv ~/.ssh ssh_backup
```

Then try to ssh into the server again, it should ask for a password. You can now restart the process of generating RSA keys.

Comment: on my local machine? you mean i should do `mv ~/.ssh ssh_backup` on my pc?

Comment: what if my pc is windows?

Comment: Then you are posting on the wrong forum. There will probably be an equivalent directory under windows but I really don't know. I would recommend you flag your question and ask a mod to migrate to superuser.

Comment: i have ubuntu 12.04 installed as well so i can do it from there, i use terminator shell, is it `.ssh ssh_backup` on ubuntu?

Comment: You should do it on the machine you cannot connect from. _If_ I have understood your problem correctly, you have generated an incorrect RSA key and ssh is trying to use it to identify you to your server. If you delete your local key, it should ask you for a password again and allow you to connect. If you cannot connect from windows but you _can_ connect from Linux (or vice versa) then the problem is with the server, not your local machine and what I suggest will not work.

Comment: it didn't work on putty nor on terminator, I'll try your solution, and will tell you if it works, but i'm not too optimistic, since i tried to login from everywhere winscp, filezilla putty and terminator (windows and linux)

Comment: It didn't work sir

Comment: No, having seen your error, it wouldn't. Try @mattdm's solution and post the output of `ssh -vv`.

Comment: please read my edit sir